# Openstreetmaps and Nominatim: Do I install both or does Nominatim include openstreetmaps?

Tags: geolocation, openstreetmap, nominatim

Just poking around with my own Openstreetmaps server and came up against a few questions.

1) I followed these instruction: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/The_Rails_Port to install Openstreetmaps, and I followed some other instructions: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation#Configure_for_use_with_Apache, to install Nominatim. **Do I really need both installed or will Nominatim install openstreet maps for me?**

2) **I am very new to mapping, can someone explain the difference between openstreetmaps and Noimatim?** I will be using the service to geolocation and not sure which to be using.

Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) (OSM's first choice for [*geocoding* and *reverse geocoding*](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines)) then you also need to install a local copy of the OSM database. This step is already included in the [Nominatim installation procedure](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation) under the section [Import and index OSM data](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation#Import_and_index_OSM_data). You need to download either the whole [planet file](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) or some [extract](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts). Also note that you probably want to perform periodic [updates](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation#Updates) to keep your local OSM database up to date.

You don't need the [rails port](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/The_Rails_Port) if you don't want to provide your own [API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) and the whole web frontend.